# How to make a extension/script/program that will refresh a browser until a certain phrase/keyword is found or is not found?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, refresh

Is there any program/extension that I can use with browser that will refresh a webpage and search for a certain phrase or text and then stop once the phrase is found or is not found.

For example say I made a site that cycles using a randomizer through the words "One," "Two," and "Three."

This program would refresh the page until the word "Three" is found, If I set it to find that word, and then stop once it is found.

OR

This program would refresh the page until the word "Three" is not found, If I set it to find that word, and then stop once it is not found.

I know that we can use curl and grep to do that, but the page is not loaded on webbrowser. This is not what I want. see if there is solution that we can load on browser as well

If there no such things exists, any idea on how to write this kind of program? use what tool to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily write an extension to do this. I would suggest instead of refreshing the page every time, you poll the data until you get the desired result then refresh the page once you find it. A short example using jQuery because I am familiar with it:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "Find Text",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Find Text",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "on.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"
 ],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["bgp.js","jquery-1.8.3.min.js"],
    "persistent": true
 }
}
```

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { width: 300px; }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Desired Search Url</div>
    <input type="text" id="searchUrl">
    <div>Desired Search Text</div>
    <input type="text" id="searchText">
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Popup.js**

```
$(function(){
  var tabId;
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tab) {
    $('#searchUrl').val(tab[0].url);
    tabId = tab[0].id;
  });
  $('#searchButton').click(function(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
      url:$('#searchUrl').val(),
      text:$('#searchText').val(),
      tab:tabId
    });
  });
});
```

**bgp.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  checkUrlForText(message.url,message.text,message.tab);
});
function checkUrlForText(url,text,tab){
  var contains;
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    async:false, 
    success: function(data){
      contains = $(':contains('+text+')',data);
      while(contains.length == 0){
        $.ajax({
          url:url,
          async:false,
          success: function(dat){
            contains = $(':contains('+text+')',dat);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  chrome.tabs.reload(tab);
}
```

If having it refresh the tab every time is a requirement (the content would change between the time it found what you were looking for and when it refreshes the page) then you should use [`content scripts`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to test for the desired value and send a message to the background page if the desired text is not there to refresh the page and start again. Like this:

**bgp.js**

```
var contains;
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  checkTabForText(message.text,message.tab);
  contains = false;
});
function checkTabForText(text,tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab,{file:"jquery-1.8.3.min.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab,{file:"checkText.js"},function(){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab, {text:text}, function(response){
      contains = response.contains;
      if(!contains){
        chrome.tabs.reload(tab,function(){
          checkTabForText(text,tab);
        });          
      }
    });
  });    
}
```

**checkText.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  var contains = $(':contains('+message.text+')');
  if(contains.length > 0)
   sendResponse({contains:true});
  else
   sendResponse({contains:false});
});
```